# How to make the <DIV> unchangeable in TINY MCE editor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor for editing HTML Contents.

I already have html template which will be loaded in Tiny MCE when the editor gets loaded.

Consider this, every time I load the editor, the following template is loaded:

```
<html>
<div id = template >Please start editing the HTML</div>
</html>
```

I dont want the user to change the above DIV in any way. I want to make it unchangeable. The user can enter whatever after the .

How to make the  unchangeable in TINY MCE editor.

Is Jquery good OR are there any Tiny MCE features which lets you achieve this.